# downgrading to rails 5.1.0 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I want to have my new rails project to be using gem rails 5.1.0 specifically, but each time I do create a "rails new project", by default it will be rails 5.2.0 in my gemfile. So what I do is I  will manually change it to rails 5.1.0 in my gemfile. However, I will get this result each time i do a bundle exec rails c:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    62: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
    61: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
    60: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
    59: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
    58: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    57: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    56: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    55: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    54: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    53: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<main>'
    52: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
    51: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
    50: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    49: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    48: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    47: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:84:in `perform'
    46: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:16:in `require_application_and_environment!'
    45: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:329:in `require_environment!'
    44: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
    43: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
    42: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
    41: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    40: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    39: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    38: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    37: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    36: from /Users/YickTing/ecommerce/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
    35: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
    34: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
    33: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    32: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    31: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    30: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    29: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    28: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    27: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    26: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
    25: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:48:in `tsort_each_child'
    24: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:48:in `each'
    23: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    22: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    21: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    20: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    19: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    18: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
    17: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    16: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    15: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:599:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    14: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:599:in `each'
    13: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:600:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    12: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
    11: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
    10: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
     9: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
     8: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     7: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
     6: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     5: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
     4: from /Users/YickTing/ecommerce/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<main>'
     3: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:211:in `configure'
     2: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:211:in `instance_eval'
     1: from /Users/YickTing/ecommerce/config/environments/development.rb:31:in `block in <main>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing': undefined method `active_storage' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x00007f817e09e258> (NoMethodError)
```

I am pretty new to rails so I dont know if there's something I missed out or something I do wrongly. Hopefully someone could enlighten me on this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

add `gem 'rails', '~> 5.1'` to gem file in your App

Try remove Gemfile.lock and re-do a bundle update eventmachine

Comment: Thanks talaatmagdy ! I managed to fixed it by clean uninstallation, but I believe your method should work as well, cheers.

Comment: Thank you! . More importantly your problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my own issue.

I ran a clean uninstallation of rails on my system using

```
gem uninstall rails
gem uninstall railties
```

And installed the gem I want again.

Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple versions of rails installed in your system, you can specify which version of Rails to create a new app with by running:

```
rails _version_ new APP_NAME
```

For example, if you want to use Rails 5.1.0 you'd run:

```
rails _5.1.0_ new APP_NAME
```

and a new rails 5.1.0 application will be created for you. Ensure you have the version of rails installed:

```
gem list \^rails\$
```